# RabbitMQ declaring multiple routing keys

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have multiple routing keys that connect with the same exchange. I have configure the routing keys separated by semicolon in my application.properties like this:

```
events.routingkey=ONLINE.UPDATE.ADDRESS.RES; ONLINE.UPDATE.ADDRESS.PHN; ONLINE.UPDATE.ADDRESS.MOB; etc....
```

[image]

After that, if i go to the monitor I see the routing keys like this, but I'm not quite sure if I should have one routing key per bind with the same exchange or if this is OK.

UPDATE: So I have changed the config class as follows:

```
 @Value("#{'${peopleevents.routingkey}'.split(',')}")
    public List<String> routingKey;
```

And then when declaring the biding how can I add every routing key to a new biding coming from the same exchage? Is there a way to do it with a for or something?

```
 @Bean
    public Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder
                .bind(queue)
                .to(exchange)
                .with(routingKey.foreach(what should I put here?););
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate binding for each routing key.

**EDIT**

If you use a comma-delimited list, you don't need SpEL, Spring will automatically split and trim the values:

```java
@Bean
Declarables bindings(@Value("${keys}") List<String> keys, DirectExchange exchange, Queue queue) {
    return new Declarables(keys.stream()
            .map(key -> BindingBuilder.bind(queue)
                    .to(exchange)
                    .with(key))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: And how can I achieve this using the application.properties?

Comment: You need to edit the question to show how you are currently processing the `events.routingkey` property.

Comment: I have post a new update

Comment: Use `Declarables`. I added an example to the answer.